# Stackpanel Visibility - what am I doing wrong . .

Tags: wpf

I want to make a ListBox containing StackPanels as its elements.  The StackPanels will be created and added at runtime, in the C# code behind.  .

The StackPanels will contain some images but at the moment none of the image stuff exists yet, so in this code I just wanted to make sure I could do the mechanics.

My XAML looks like this:

```
<Grid>        
    <ListBox Name="listBoxImages" BorderBrush="DarkGray" Width="600" Height="300" BorderThickness="3" 
             Margin="0" Padding="0" Background="#FFC0C0C0"/>    
</Grid>
```

In the C# code-behind I deliberately set a background color of the Listbox different from the one in the XAML to verify I was accessing the ListBox properly in the code-behind.

```
listBoxImages.Background = Brushes.Blue;  //just to show I'm accessing it . . .
```

That part works; the ListBox displays blue.
Then I went to add a StackPanel.   Since there's nothing in it yet I gave it a height and width and a different background color, but I don't see anything.   So I checked its visibility and it's false.    So I tried setting the visibility using *System.Windows.Visibility.Visible* but it's still false after that.

```
    StackPanel myStackPanel = new StackPanel();
    myStackPanel.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    myStackPanel.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
    myStackPanel.Background = Brushes.Bisque;  // make something visible
    myStackPanel.MinHeight = 50;
    myStackPanel.Width = 50;
    bool bResult = myStackPanel.IsVisible;
    myStackPanel.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    bResult = myStackPanel.IsVisible;
    myStackPanel.Margin = new Thickness(10); 
    listBoxImages.Items.Add(myStackPanel);
```

Why is the StackPanel visibility false and is that the reason why I don't see it after adding it to the ListBox?  (I'm sorry if this is a noob question)

Comment: "what am I doing wrong?" Everything. You shouldn't create UI elements in code. Use an appropriate DataTemplate for your ListBox items instead, by setting the ListBox's `ItemTemplate` property. See [Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx).

Comment: @Clemens - your answer doesn't explain why I don't see a stack panel in my UI.  In any case, following your link makes data templating looked like overkill and a lot more coding than what I'll need for my purposes.  I don't need the flexibility that data templating provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IsVisible is set to true when it gets rendered on UI.

You can verify by hooking to Loaded event and see value of IsVisible in it by putting breakpoint on the handler.

```
myStackPanel.Loaded += (s, e) => bResult = myStackPanel.IsVisible;
```

Also, I verified with your posted code and can see StackPanel rendered on UI.

---

More verbose definition:

```
    .........
    listBoxImages.Items.Add(myStackPanel);
    myStackPanel.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(myStackPanel_Loaded);
}

void myStackPanel_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bool isVisible = (sender as StackPanel).IsVisible;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the syntax of the "myStackPanel.Loaded += (s, e) => bResult = myStackPanel.IsVisible;"    But then why don't I see the StackPanel rendered?     I just see a big blue ListBox.

Comment: @user316117 - I have added more verbose definition. Place breakpoint there and see what is the value of isVisible?

Comment: Fascinating.   After I put your diagnostic code in it worked.  Not only was it set to visible but it actually BECAME visible, i.e., I could see it.   Weird.  But at least it works now, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Listbox is better populated with an items template. If you want to add arbitrary controls of different types, just use a stack panel.

Comment: I want a scrollable list of stack panels.   Each one will contain a linear list of images.

Comment: Stack panel of stack panels? They can have scroll bars too.